# Download binary file using poco c++ library

Tags: c++, download, poco

I followed the download.cpp example in Poco Github in order to fix code for downloading binary file. The code is

```
    std::string url_test ="http://my_webpage/file.bin";
    URI uri_test (url_test);
    std::auto_ptr<std::istream> pStr(URIStreamOpener::defaultOpener().open(uri_test));
    std::string data;
    Poco::StreamCopier::copyToString(*pStr.get(), data);
    std::string::size_type size = data.size();
```

I have two questions regarding the above

1. what if I'm behind a proxy server, how can I pass the proxy server
   arguments?
2. Since I want to calculate current download speed of large
   files how can I get dynamically the size of the file instead of
   waiting for the whole download to end ?

Please share your opinions.